# C# extension by OmniSharp not working in VS Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

When I open a project o got this error:

> Starting OmniSharp server at 21.08.2017, 21:43:58
>       Target: c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega
>
> OmniSharp server started
>       Path: C:\Users\flaur.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.12.1.omnisharp\OmniSharp.exe
>       PID: 8684
>
> OmniSharp: -s c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega --hostPID 1416 --stdio
>   DotNet:enablePackageRestore=false --encoding utf-8 --loglevel
>   information formattingOptions:useTabs=false
>   formattingOptions:tabSize=4 formattingOptions:indentationSize=4
>   [info]: OmniSharp.Startup
>           Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega' on host 1416. [info]:
>   OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
>           Initializing in c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega [info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
>           Auto package restore: False [info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
>           Update workspace context [info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
>           Resolving projects references [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
>           Omnisharp will use local MSBuild.
>       MSBUILD_EXE_PATH: C:\Users\flaur.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.12.1.omnisharp\msbuild\MSBuild.exe
>       MSBuildExtensionsPath: C:\Users\flaur.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.12.1.omnisharp\msbuild
>
> [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
>           No solution files found in 'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega' [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
>           Loading project: c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega\Vega.csproj [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo
>           Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Vega.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache". Access
>   to the path
>   'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Vega.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache'
>   is denied. [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
>           Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega\Vega.csproj'.
>   c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega\Vega.csproj
>
> [info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega'. [info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Could not find any CSX files [info]: OmniSharp.Services.WorkspaceHelper
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
>   [info]: OmniSharp.Startup
>           Configuration finished.

Cand someone help ?

Comment: "Access to the path 'c:\Users\flaur\Desktop\vega\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Vega.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache' is denied. " either a permission problem or something else has a file locked.

Comment: I got this on every project, and I don't have any restriction on thath file.

Comment: Better file a bug report against vscode on Github.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes, my antivirus dosen't allow a program to run(Bitdefender)